# Down votes on all my recent answers?

Tags: discussion, support, down-votes, serial-voting

**UPDATE:** The serial down votes were reversed, and I got all my points back. Thanks everyone!

I just noticed the following on my feed:

[image]

The questions that were down voted for no reason are: [{1}](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/750312/how-to-find-lim-x-to-ln-2-frac2e3x-163e2x-12/750318#750318), [{2}](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/750075/first-order-ode-problem/750110#750110), [{3}](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/751163/length-of-an-astroid/751193#751193), [{4}](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/748990/find-the-total-distance-that-the-particle-travels-over-the-given-interval/749014#749014), [{5}](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/745925/primitive-of-that-function/745966#745966), and [{6}](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/742824/total-time-a-ball-bounces-for-from-a-height-of-8-feet-and-rebounds-to-a-height-5/742881#742881). I suspect that the person who down voted them did so out of contempt.

Is this allowed? And will mods do something about it? Or is the only solution to fight fire with fire?

Thanks.

Comment: I think naming names is not a good strategy. In particular since you can't be sure that you're naming the right name. But that incident should be caught by the serial-voting script, the votes will probably be reversed around 3 a.m. (UTC).

Comment: @DanielFischer I thought that too after I posted it. My apologies. Removed.

Comment: Over the years, civic authorities have generally found that it is better to fight fire with water.

Comment: @Gerry: There was an episode of MacGyver where he fought fire with dynamite and won. But then again, that was nearly 30 years ago.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is this allowed?

No, serial downvoting is not allowed.

> And will mods do something about it?

Better. An automated script should reverse it within 24 hours.

> Or is the only solution to fight fire with fire?

Please do not.